# Boundary of the sequence $1/n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology. For an arbitrary set of $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$, let $A'$ be the complement of $A$ and $A^-$ be the closure of $A$. Finally, let $\partial A$ be the boundary of the set $A$.

Let $E=\lbrace 1/n : n\in\mathbb{N} \rbrace$. What is $\partial E$?

At first, I thought that the boundary would be the empty set. But then, using the definition of the boundary $\partial E=E^-\cap E^{'-}$ I have that, since all the points in $E$ are isolated, $E^-=E$. Further, some limit points in the complement $E^-$ can be the elements of $E$, i.e. $E\subset E^{'-}$. Therefore $\partial E = E$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Just because all the points of $E$ are isolated doesn’t mean $E^{-}=E.$

Comment: Note that $\bar E=E\cup\{0\}$ (as for writing I think `\bar` $\bar E$, `\complement` $E^\complement$ and `\mathring` $\mathring{E}$ are more common for closure, complement and interior)

Comment: Ah yeah, that's right, it should be $E^-=E \cup \lbrace 0 \rbrace$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bar E=E\cup\{0\}$.  And $\overline {E'}=\Bbb R$.

Thus $\partial E=E\cup\{0\}$.